# How to properly load a font-family for my custom library components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, uicomponents

I'm writing a new React UI component library using `styled-components` and `styled-system`. This library will be used on a side project and should be published as a npm library.

I'm creating a button component and considering almost every component should have a `font-family` `Roboto` like this:

```
const BaseButton = styled.div`
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
`;
```

Considering that each component is independent from each other, where is the best place to set a default `font-family` once for my entire component library?

Thank you

Comment: Much like a standard stylesheet, adding it to one of the top most components should  add it to all child components, shouldn't it? Much like adding the default font to the html element.

Comment: Hey @technicallynick the problem is there is no top most component like an "App", to create libraries we only export all the components on a single file like an index.js.

Comment: In the case of libraries, could you not wrap your components in a parent with any default settings? If you centralize your exports to one file for calling (while maintaining each component in its own individual file), could you not add a wrapper container just prior to the export? By no means am I an expert in libraries or even styled-components. I am just spit-balling some ideas.

Comment: @technicallynick I really appreciate your help. I'm thinking of creating a `withTheme` `hoc` and use on all componentes files, like: withTheme(Button), withTheme(Badge), etc.

Comment: You could try exporting all your components from 1 main file and then import the font-family through Fontsource (which is an npm library). https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource/blob/master/packages/roboto/README.md

Answer (score 5):

If you want mostly all your components to use Roboto you should set the @font-face up globally.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import Roboto from './Roboto.otf';
import SecondaryFont from './SecondaryFont.otf';

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('${Roboto}') format('opentype');
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'SecondaryFont';
    src: url('${SecondaryFont}') format('opentype');
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
`

const YourCustomProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyles />
    {children}
  </>
)

// Inform users to wrap their app with your provider
const App = () => {
  return (
    <YourCustomProvider>
      // Their app
    </YourCustomProvider>
  )
}
```

Then to use the secondary font on specific components.

```
const RandomComponent = styled.div`
  font-family: "SecondaryFont"
`
```

Comment: Hey @Mark, thank you for the answer. I'm creating a ui component library, so I don't have the "App" to use GlobalStyles.

Comment: Did you figure this out @RodLima ? I'm trying to solve the same issue.

Comment: @shoke nops, if you find a solution please post it here.

Comment: @RodLima @b.lit have you guys considered creating a `Provider` for your component library? That's how UI-Kitten does it for example. I'll update my answer to include it, see here, https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/getting-started#manual-installation